# Really long line of JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, syntax

I have this really long line of JQuery and too many quotes. It's tripping me up:

```
$('("<img>", { src: oembed.thumbnail_url, width:200 }).children("img").wrap("<div class="thumbnail_border" />")').insertBefore("div#heard_div");
```

And so the question is what is the correct syntax for this line.

Comment: You are correct, you do have a long line of jQuery. What is the issue? What is it meant to do?

Comment: my question is what is the correct syntax for this line.

Comment: What's the point of still voting this down without any comments? The user has already edited his question...

Comment: @sra, hover your mouse over the down-arrow. This question still matches all of those claims.

Comment: please specify your intention, everyone could just come up with hundreds of "syntax fix", and they all work differently

Comment: ok i figured it out... i want this question to be deleted... everyone vote to delete it.

Answer (score 6):

That line is so wrong in so many ways...

```
$('<img src="'+oembed.thumbnail_url+'" />')
    .width(200)
    .wrap('<div class="thumbnail_border" />')
    .insertBefore("#heard_div");
```

No idea why you are trying to select the `img` children within the newly created `img` element because it isn't allowed to contain any other elements.

You should take a look at the awesome book [jQuery Fundamentals](http://jqfundamentals.com/) by Rebeccca Murphey.

Also, I am really wondering what your question is :)

Comment: My question is what is the correct syntax for my line. Plus what you wrote doesn't work at all.

Comment: @user730569, my line works just fine if taken out of context. Please check the StackOverflow [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) and learn to ask questions properly.

Comment: Let me give you a hint; there's a good chance that none of the code you are getting in the answers is going to work. You asked for correct syntax, not how to make it work in your context.

Comment: It might be correct syntax but my jquery code is part of a plugin that this syntax is not compatible with

Comment: Also, @Marcus Ekwall, any reason why you chose the full img tag instead of $('img [src=' + var + ']) ?

Comment: @user730569, say what? Why wasn't this mentioned in your question, and why aren't you showing us more code? We're not mind readers.

Comment: Speak for yourself. I have ESPN.

Comment: @melee, by adding the whole tag we tell jQuery to create a new element, and not to query the DOM for a preexisting element. Since that is what he had in his original line of code, I thought that this is what he wanted (as he is using `insertBefore` as well, which probably means it isn't in the DOM to begin with).

Comment: which version of jquery you are using? It will not below 1.4.x

Comment: @melee, I'll refer to [jQuery Fundamentals](http://jqfundamentals.com/#example-3.29) on that one ;)

Comment: @melee your getting confused between DOM selection and DOM creation. A element created in jQuery shorthand is written like so: `$('<div>')` which jQuery internally does `document.createElement` -- a native Javascript method which creates an element. If you did `$('div')` (notice there are not any `<>`) then this is called a CSS selector and it's a major fundamental part of selecting prexisting elements. Take a look at http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Comment: I just realised I said @melee, I meant @user730569 :D

Comment: @Gary, well @melee seems a bit confused about it as well ;)

Comment: Oh I was right to say @melee, he was the one getting confused. Oh man is it really 8am and no coffee yet 8)

Comment: @Gary, 10pm here and on my 4th cup already :D

Comment: @Gary Green yeah, I know my selectors pretty well, but I've never used it for shorthand DOM creation. I've never had a use for it, haha

Answer (score 3):

I'm only doing this b/c I'm bored...

```
$('<img>', { src: oembed.thumbnail_url, width:200 })
.children("img")
.wrap('<div class="thumbnail_border" />')
.insertBefore("div#heard_div");
```

... but you'll probably get a lot of flack for this type of "question" as it's basically a "do my work for me" request.

BTW: I have no idea what you're trying to do with that bit of code, I've just fixed the quote issue.

Comment: It doesn't work because you've got a really weird selector.

Comment: I believe he wants to create an `img` element. The `.children("img")` doesn't make any sense though...

Comment: @Marcus ~ yeah, I actually did a triple-take on that.

Comment: @user730569 instead of saying "this doesn't work", please tell us "how it should work"